# How can I explicitly define an order in which Spring's out-of-the-box process of reading properties out of an available-in-classpath application.yml

Tags: spring, configuration, yaml

UPDATE: I just published this question also [here](http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-inject-into-my-Configuration-class-which-reads-properties-from-external-source-in-my-case-zookeeper-and-makes-them-available-for-other-beans-system-properties-which-were-read-earlier-into-memory-from-files-by-spring-boot-ConfigFileApplicationListener), I might have done a better work phrasing it there.

How can I explicitly define an order in which Spring's out-of-the-box process of reading properties out of an available-in-classpath `application.yml` will take place BEFORE my `@Configuration` annotated class which reads configuration data from zookeeper and places them as system properties which are later easily read and injected into members using `@Value`?

I have a `@Configuration` class, which defines a creation of a `@Bean`, in a which configuration data from zookeeper is read and placed as system properties, in a way that they can easily be read and injected into members using `@Value`.

```
@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
public class ZookeeperConfigurationReader {

    @Value("${zookeeper.url}")
    static String zkUrl;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer zkPropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesConfigurerAdapter propertiesAdapter = new PropertySourcesConfigurerAdapter();
        new ConfigurationBuilder().populateAdapterWithDataFromZk(propertiesAdapter);
        return propertiesAdapter.getConfigurer();
    }

    public void populateAdapterWithDataFromZk(ConfigurerAdapter ca) {
      ...
    }

}
```

Right now I pass the `zookeeper.url` into the executed program using a `-Dzookeeper.url` which is added to the execution line. Right now I read it by calling directly `System.getProperty("zookeeper.url")`.

Since I'm using Spring-Boot application, I also have a `application.yml` configuration file.

I would like to be able to set the `zookeeper.url` in the `application.yml`, and keep my execution line clean as possible from explicit properties.

The mission turns out to be harder than I thought.

As you can see in the above code sniplet of `ZookeeperConfigurationReader`, I'm trying to inject that value using `@Value("${zookeeper.url}")` into a member in the class which performs the actual read of data from zookeeper, but at the time the code that needs that value accesses it, it is still null. The reason for that is that in spring life cycle wise, I'm still in the phase of "configuration" as I'm a `@Configuration` annotated class myself, and the spring's code which reads the application.yml data and places them as system properties, hasn't been executed yet.

So bottom line, what I'm looking for is a way to control the order and tell spring to first read `application.yml` into system properties, and then load `ZookeeperConfigurationReader` class.

Comment: consider a different process. if you use additional products from the Hadoop family which, themselves, make use of zookeeper (for example - HDFS with high-availability configuration) then read the configuration from the $HADOOP_CONF directory and find out where zookeeper is. i think it's better than duplicating the values

Comment: I do use hadoop. only that my micro services are completely isolated and unaware if its existence. making them aware of it and its configuration files just for the sake of finding the location of zk doesn't make so much sense. besides, it doesn't answer my question - unless what you offer is to manually find, load and parse the values in this file and not using spring's build it ability to read properties by simply using @Value. if I'm going towards a direction of manually reading properties, I might as well read it from application.yml in my classpath.

Comment: if you'll check, you'll find out that you already have the hadoop conf set for other services (e.g. query). this should happen for all services. in time you'll find out that zk is not the only information you need to extract from there (assuming your architect knows what he's doing). read the zk info from the hadoop configuration files (as a configuration module of spring) and publish the values to the rest of the context. make sure you do it from a reusable library that can serve all services.

Comment: Your advice makes sense. Unfortunately it cannot be applied in my case. Your assumption "in time you'll find out that zk is not the only information you need to extract from there" is wrong. I have just learned that our system has a different deployment configuration in which hadoop is not part of (e.g. webmind) hence it doesn't make sense to enforce on them the presence and parsing of `core-sites.xml` just for the sake of getting `ha.zookeeper.quorum` out of it. I have just realized that the only way to make my configuration library usable cross all possible services is using plain old -D

Comment: i disagree. you should follow this pattern even when only part of your application is deployed. you need to see the bigger picture (deployment, etc.). anyway, your funeral

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Spring Cloud Zookeeper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper). I posted a brief example of use [here](http://therore.net/distributed-configuration-with-zookeeper-curator-and-spring-cloud-config/)